Smoothness of quotient of compact Hausdorff topological group
Let $G$ be a compact Hausdorff topological group and $H\le G$ a closed subgroup such that the topological space $G/H$ admits the structure of a smooth manifold. Does there necessarily exists a normal subgroup $N\trianglelefteq G$ with $N\le H$ such that $G/N$ is a smooth manifold (and therefore a compact Lie group)?
In the case,that $G/H$ is zero-dimensional this is true. One may take $N:=\bigcap_{g\in G} gHg^{-1} \le H$. Take a set of left translates of $H$, i.e. $G/H=\{g_1H, \dots, g_n H\}$. Then, $N=\bigcap_{i=1}^n g_i H g_i^{-1}$ and $G/N$ injects into  $\prod_{i=1}^n G/g_i H g_i^{-1}$. Thus, $G/N$ is also finite and discrete. Can one generalize this argument, maybe using topological dimension instead of cardinality?
In the general case, $G/N \to \text{Aut}_G(G/H),\; gN \mapsto (g'H\mapsto g'gH)$ is a continuous group isomorphism. Here, $\text{Aut}_G(G/H)$ is the group of $G$-equivariant homeomorphisms of $G/H$ topologized as a subgroup of the compact open topology. So, it suffices to show that $\text{Aut}_G(G/H)$ is a finite dimensional Lie group. Suppose I added the hypothesis, that $G$ acts via diffeomorphisms on $G/H$, then $G/N$ embeds into $\text{Diff}(G/H)$, an  infinite dimensional Lie group. Thus, $G/N$ is itself a Lie group and, by compactness, finite dimensional.
